# Newlines are not translated to space within texescape of listings

Tags: listings

I try to use the listings package to typeset C code, such that C comments
are interpreted as input to \LaTeX. One line comments are easy with `texcl`option,

```
\begin{lstlisting}[texcl]
 main(){main();}//\LaTeX
\end{lstlisting}
```

But, this option applies only to line comments

```
 \begin{lstlisting}[texcl]
 main(){main();}/*\LaTeX*/
 \end{lstlisting}
```

The `escapeinside` option can be used instead,

```
 \begin{LTXexample}
 \begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={/*}{*/}]
  main(){main();}/*\LaTeX*/
 \end{lstlisting}
```

With `escapebegin` and `escapeend` we can even make the output look
very much like the input, with a bit of polishing

```
  \begin{lstlisting}[
   escapeinside={/*}{*/},
   escapebegin={\texttt{/*}},
escapeend={\texttt{*/}}]
main(){main();}/*\LaTeX*/
\end{lstlisting}
```

*Detour* Why would I want to make the output look like the input? I envision a poor man's version of web/tangle/weave in which code written within a version of a listings
environment is not only presented nicely on the rendered document, it is also saved in a file named `\jobname.c`, which can be compiled by a C compiler.
This file should also make sense to a person who has very little understanding of \LaTeX. Something like

```
\lstnewenvironment{code}{
\lstset{frame=single,
  escapeinside={/*}{*/},
  escapebegin={\texttt{/*}\itshape}, 
  escapeend={\texttt{*/}}}}{\footnote
    {Should be saved in \jobname.c}}
  \begin{code}
   main(){main();}/*\LaTeX*/
  \end{code}
```

The problem is that escaping to \LaTeX does not work quite right, and new line
characters in the input disappear

```
 \begin{code}
 /* The shortest legal (but not warnings free) C 
  program.*/ 
  main(){for(;;);}
\end{code}
```

There is yet another small glitch I think with the escaping mechanism; it seems to
be adding a space.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={/*}{*/}]
 /* This is the time for all good men to come to the */
 main(){main();}/*\LaTeX*/
\end{lstlisting}
```

The following is is a latex document to demonstrate the question

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,showexpl}
\begin{document}
I try to use the listings package to typeset C code, such that C comments 
are interpreted as input to \LaTeX. 
\begin{LTXexample}
\lstset{language=C}
\end{LTXexample}
One line comments are easy with \verb/texcl/ 
option,

\begin{LTXexample}
\begin{lstlisting}[texcl]
main(){main();}//\LaTeX
\end{lstlisting}
\end{LTXexample}
But, this option applies only to line comments 
\begin{LTXexample}
\begin{lstlisting}[texcl]
main(){main();}/*\LaTeX*/
\end{lstlisting}
\end{LTXexample}
The \verb/escapeinside/ option can be used instead, 
\begin{LTXexample}
 \begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={/*}{*/}]
main(){main();}/*\LaTeX*/
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{LTXexample}
 With \verb/escapebegin/ and \verb/escapeend/ we can even make the output look 
very much like the input, with a bit of polishing 
\begin{LTXexample}
\begin{lstlisting}[
    escapeinside={/*}{*/},
    escapebegin={\texttt{/*}},
    escapeend={\texttt{*/}}]
main(){main();}/*\LaTeX*/
\end{lstlisting}
\end{LTXexample}
\paragraph{Detour} Why would I want to make the output look like the input? I envision a poor man's version of web/tangle/weave in which code written within a version of a listings
environment is not only presented nicely on the rendered document, it is also saved in a file named \verb/\jobname.c/, which can be compiled by a C compiler.
This file should also make sense to a person who has very little understanding of \LaTeX. Something like 

\begin{LTXexample}
 \lstnewenvironment{code}{
    \lstset{frame=single,
      escapeinside={/*}{*/},
      escapebegin={\texttt{/*}\itshape}, 
      escapeend={\texttt{*/}}}}{\footnote
        {Should be saved in \jobname.c}}
\begin{code}
main(){main();}/*\LaTeX*/
\end{code}
\end{LTXexample}

The problem is that escaping to \LaTeX does not work quite right, and new line
characters in the input disappear
\begin{code}
/* The shortest legal (but not warnings free) C 
program.*/ 
main(){for(;;);}
\end{code}
There is yet another small glitch I think with the escaping mechanism; it seems to 
be adding a space.
\begin{LTXexample}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={/*}{*/}]
/* This is the time for all good men to come to the */
main(){main();}/*\LaTeX*/
\end{lstlisting}
\end{LTXexample}
```

Comment: you can avoid it by ending every line with space + percent `may %`. Beside this, I would suggest to write the author.

Comment: Indeed! Let me clarify the question so that it is better understood why this will not meet the purpose of this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to respect the newlines in a multi-line escaped environment
is to define explicitly what a newline character should do.
The following is an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\lstset{language=C}

{%
    \makeatletter
    \catcode13=13\relax% Make ASCII 13 active to define it later
    \gdef\newlinewillbreakandindent{%
        \lst@CalcColumn% Record the column position of slash-star
        \xdef\slashstarposition{\the\numexpr\@tempcnta+2}
        \itshape% Apply some formatting here, not relevant.
        \def^^M{% What should I do whenever I see ASCII 13?
            \\% first, break the line
            \hbox{}\hskip\slashstarposition\lst@width% then, indent to proper column
        }%
    }%
}

\lstnewenvironment{Ccode}{
    \lstset{
        frame=single,
        escapeinside={/*}{*/},
        escapebegin={\texttt{/*}\bgroup\newlinewillbreakandindent},
        escapeend={\egroup\texttt{*/}}
    }
}{\footnote{Should be saved in \jobname.c}}

\begin{Ccode}
    /* The shortest legal
       (but not warnings free)
       C program. */
    main(){for(;;);}
\end{Ccode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, I was not able to make the frame work (no pun).
I give up here.

Comment: Frames can be drawn afterwards. I like your approach! Also good to know that carriage returns are encountered at the end of the line, even for source files using just line feeds.

Comment: Yeah, somehow that's how TeX works on my machine. ^^M (that is, ASCII 13) for detecting lines in the source file, and ^^J (that is, ASCII 10) for making lines in stdout by `\message{}`.

Comment: Forgot a `%` after `\@tempcnta+2}` ~ ~ ~ my bad.

Comment: For some reason, this breaks when I set escapechar to back quote

Comment: @YossiGil MWE by gist? I didn't use back quote at all so that's really really weird.